# How to get Selected Country Id from DropdownList and pass to State Dropdown using React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have two DropDown list, CountryData and StateData.I is able to get country list in dropdown, but cannot get the state data list according to country id. So I just want to get the state data list according to Selected country id. Please tell me how to pass Selected country id in state data. Please let me know if you have a different idea.Here is my two Dropdown please checkit.

```
   componentDidMount() {
 //  Country Data API
  const url = 'http://161.35.123.112:4000/device/country-lists'
 fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
      const CountryDropdownData = responseJson.message.map(item => ({ value: item.name, 
 CountryId: item.id }));
    this.setState({       
      CountryDropdownData
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
  // State Data API 
   fetch('http:161.35.123.112:4000/device/state-lists', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       countryId : "here i want to get selected country id"

     })
   }).then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
      const StateDropdownData = responseJson.message.map(item => ({ value: 
   item.name }));
      this.setState({

         StateDropdownData 
      })        
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
   }

 <Dropdown
        data={this.state.CountryDropdownData} 
        containerStyle={styles.dropdownStyle} pickerStyle= 
     {styles.dropdownPicker}
        valueExtractor={({ value}) => value}
        onChangeText={TextInputCountry => this.setState({ TextInputCountry 
      })}
        defaultValue="Country"
      ></Dropdown>

   <Dropdown
        data={this.state.StateDropdownData}
        containerStyle={styles.dropdownStyle} pickerStyle= 
   {styles.dropdownPicker}
      valueExtractor={({ value }) => value}
        onChangeText={TextInputState => this.setState({ TextInputState })}         
        defaultValue="State"
      ></Dropdown>
```

Comment: What is the type of `TextInputState` ? is it an object?

Comment: this.state = {  
      TextInputCity: ' ',
      TextInputState:  ' ', 
      CountryDropdownData : [],
      StateDropdownData : [],
      CityDropdownData : [],
    };
 }

Comment: I am interested in how will get `id` of selected country?